# JDK path in IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, java-8, windows-10

I have the JDK path in IntelliJ IDEA set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8` , nevertheless, when I go to the file system I am not able to find this path, and I show all the hidden files !

[image]

I can also access to the folder from the IntelliJ IDEA terminal, but not from the command line:

[image]

```
C:\>cd "C:\Program Files\Java"
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>cd C:\Program Files\Java
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: What does the folder show when you input "ls"? - have you tried typing cd "C:\Program Files\Java" instead of "cd Java"?

Comment: @AdilOoze Btw, `ls` will not work in cmd. The command would be `dir`.

Comment: `ls` will only work if you open a `PowerShell` (or whatever name Microsoft gives to the pseudo-bash)

Comment: What says ```where java``` in cmd? Could you type it and compare in cmd from intellij and from windows?

Comment: Restart your IDE. It shouldn't display if it's not installed.

Comment: 1. Perform `cd C:\Program Files` and then `dir` command inside the folder to list out all the files and directories. 2. Ensure there isn't a symlink to the actual JDK installation somewhere else that IntelliJ might be referencing to. 3. When you face platform-specific issue, do not miss out on mentioning detailed versions of both the platform and the IDE in use.

Comment: Have you tried running the Command Prompt as an administrator? Windows key -> type "cmd" -> right-click on "Command Prompt" -> Run as administrator -> Yes.

Comment: Search for the current folder by pressing Shift + Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the **IntelliJ IDEA** to check whether it's displaying the same in **SDK** tab.

If it is still showing the same, then, it may be a **bug of the software**. Generally, it should not show as it's not installed.

**Note:** *Now, as you know that Java 8 is not installed on your system but IDE is showing that it is installed. You can do one thing :*

**Create a small Java project with sample classes, then try to compile it. If it is not compiling and giving error, then you will be assured that it's not installed.**

> This will mean that IDE is not updating itself and it's keeping
> the old record.

Last option, install JDK 1.8 and reinstall Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of such a situation is some wrong path set in the `PATH` environment variable. Let's assume `echo %PATH%` prints the following:

```
C:\Path X;C:\Path Y;D:\Path Z;
```

However, when you go to the environment variables window, you see a longer path. It means that the path after `D:\Path Z` is wrong and therefore the next strings in the `PATH` variable will throw this error.

To troubleshoot the problem, `echo %PATH%` and see if it prints your Java path in the output. If not, now you know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to do the following in your command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files>dir | findstr /I "Java"
```

You should have something like this (mind the `"<DIR>"`):

```
13/11/2019  22:30    <DIR>          Java
```

It's possible that you have a symlink, junction or something like that, messing up your system. Well, it's not messing up your system, but maybe your application can't handle it. In that case, you might redefine your variable on the directory your symlink or junction is referring to.

Comment: No result on this :-(

Comment: ... and what if you verify this using Windows explorer? Maybe the directory is there but it's not shown because of some file/directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path by doing the follow

This-PC -> System properties-> advanced system settings -> environment variable

Then add the path to your java bin folder
like this
C://program files/Java/jdk1.8/bin

Apply/save

Then go back to CMD and type javac or java

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is related to the version of Intellij you are running (x86 or x64).

On 32 bit applications the only available directory for program files is the "Program Files (x86)" and is shown for them as "Program Files".

(see https://www.howtogeek.com/129178/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder/ ).

If this is the issue, you will be able to find the JDK under:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk8"